# Identify the location of the ContextMenu in a Canvas?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a ContextMenu, associated to a Canvas

```
<UserControl>
  <Grid myGrid>
    <Canvas myCanvas>
      <ContextMenu myMenu />...
```

I clicked on a menuItem entry, and would like to insert at this place a control (label, myLabel).

How should I set the coordinates for myLabel, in order that it corresponds to the mouse rightclick (the ContextMenu actual "location")?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the ContextMenu's [TranslatePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.translatepoint.aspx) method, e.g. in a MenuItem's Click event handler, like this:

```
Point location = myMenu.TranslatePoint(new Point(), myCanvas);
```

where myMenu is the ContextMenu:

```
<UserControl> 
    <Grid ...> 
        <Canvas ...> 
            <ContextMenu Name=myMenu />...
```

Here's how you can get the ContextMenu from the sender of a MenuItem's Click event:

```
FrameworkElement parent = sender as FrameworkElement;
while (parent != null && !(parent is ContextMenu))
{
    parent = parent.Parent as FrameworkElement;
}
```

Comment: the sender in click will be the MenuItem, not the ContextMenu... So don't know how to find the ContextMenu...

Comment: You can set the ContextMenu's `Name` property.

Comment: Yes, but what if I have 2 context menus on the same Canvas that appears in some conditions... )